# How to delete S3 object from vbs script using REST API

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, vbscript

A widely known vbs script has been circulated for putting files to Amazon S3 from a Windows server using the REST API, and it works great for automated backup.  The REST API also includes a delete operation for files, but I haven't seen any working scripts anywhere, and my own humble efforts failed.

This works (put operation, partial code):

```
...
StringToSign = Replace("PUT\n\napplication/octet-stream\n\nx-amz-date:" & gmtDateStr & "\n/"& AWS_BUCKETNAME & sRemoteFilePath, "\n", vbLf)
...
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
.open "PUT", AWSBucketUrl & sRemoteFilePath, False
...
```

This doesn't work:

```
...
StringToSign = Replace("DELETE\n\ntext/plain\n\nx-amz-date:" & gmtDateStr & "\n/"& AWS_BUCKETNAME & sRemoteFilePath, "\n", vbLf)
...
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
.open "DELETE", AWSBucketUrl & sRemoteFilePath, False
...
```

The error returned is "SignatureDoesNotMatch -- The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."  Since the put operation works fine, the error seems not to be in the key and signing method.  Perhaps the StringToSign in the attempted delete code is not right.

Has anyone ever made this sort of thing work, or is the error in the code evident?

Comment: The mime type in the `StringToSign` seems wrong, compared to what is passed to the `PUT` example. Why is it `text/plain`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a `Content-Type` header in a `DELETE` request, because you aren't sending content.

Since there is no `Content-Type` header, you leave this element set to empty string in the string to sign.  Leave all the `\n` as they are.

Comment: The S3 documentation is ambiguous: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html
The syntax block does not include Content-Type bud does include Content-Length.  Then the sample request lower on the page includes Content-Type but not Content-Length.  The sample request with versioning includes both.  Head spins.

Comment: Aha!  If the error message shows the target string, the problem is:  the delete request string-to-sign omits the "x-amz-date:" which was present with the put request.  When I remove that, it works.  The date itself is still required.

Comment: Replacing deleted comment, which would have been first in the sequence: thanks, Michael -- your suggestion was plausible and put me on a track to realize the  <StringToSign> item in the S3 xml error message was actually the target string (not reading back what I had submitted).  The "text/plain" is actually there.  It comes back as:
`<StringToSign>DELETE

text/plain
Wed, 1 Mar 2017 19:23:13 UTC
/bucket/folder/file</StringToSign>`

Comment: @user1207313 Yes.  The signing process uses [HMAC-SHA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), which isn't reversible.  S3 can't determine what string you actually signed -- it can only determine what string you *should have* signed, based on the request you sent... and as you have now concluded, that's what's in the error response.  Including `Content-Type` in the request is still arguably wrong, but as long as the signature matches the actual request, you may get away with it.